# How to get URL of uploaded image in Firebase 5.0.4?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I upload image into server:

```
const fileData = await fb.storage().ref(`ads/my_img.jpg`).put(image)
```

In early version for get URL of uploaded image required:

```
const imageSrc = fileData.metadata.downloadURLs[0]
```

But in 5.0.4 it's doesn't work.

In docs `downloadURLs` deprecated:

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 * Use Reference.getDownloadURL instead. This property will be removed in a
 * future release.
 */
downloadURLs: string[];
```

But `getDownloadURL` method of `interface Reference` I can't figure it out how to use it.

After upload file, I need to get the URL for rendering image from server. Something like this:

```
const fileData = await fb.storage().ref(`ads/${ad.key}.${imageExt}`).put(image)
const imageSrc = fileData.metadata.downloadURLs[0]

commit('createAd', {imageSrc})
```

How to rewrite `downloadURLs[0]` for Firebase 5.0.4 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const fileData = await fb.storage().ref(`ads/${ad.key}.${imageExt}`).put(image)
const imageSrc = await fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Download url is returned in result snapshot like following:

```
const fileData = fb.storage().ref(`ads/${ad.key}.${imageExt}`).put(image)
.then((snapshot) =>{
    console.log(snapshot.downloadURL);
}
```

Or you can get download URL of an existing object like this

```
storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log(url)
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

This snipped was taken from [firebase developer page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files). I'd recommend you to check out that page in case you have any questions. Most of the times you might find your answer there.

Comment: yes I see that, but snapshot.downloadURL always undefined.

Comment: well, the second one should definitely work then. 

uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });

Answer (score 0):

What to take from the **storage** the path **ImageSrc** and save to the **database** must be deleted

```
const imageSrc = fileData.metadata.downloadURLs[0]
```

and prescribe instead

```
const imageSrc = await fb.storage().ref().child(fileData.ref.fullPath).getDownloadURL()
```

Answer (score -1):

`const imageSrc = await fileData.ref.getDownloadURL()`